# How to grant access to s3 image url to specific cloud service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When an image is uploaded in s3 by default the urls are private. I can make them public by adding permissions on the console but i don't want to do that for every image, want to automate it. I am using a non AWS cloud services for which accesses the image via the url. The service cannot access the image because the urls are private. How do i make the urls public to particular service? Making the entire bucket public is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual objects in S3 can be made public by setting the request header `x-amz-acl: public-read` in the initial upload request, when the object is created.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html#put-object-acl-specific-request-headers

Public "to a particular service" is not a valid concept.  S3 has no sense of which "service" is accessing it (unless the "service" happens to be CloudFront, which has Origin Access Identities that it can use to authorize downloads, but I suspect that not to be relevant, here).  If the service uses URLs as-provided, you can simply submit a pre-signed URL to the service, so that the download is authorized.

Comment: How do create pre-signed urls?

Comment: The service which accesses the image via URL is Google Cloud Vision.

Comment: There are a number of ways, bit the simplest is probably `aws s3 presign` using the [cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).

Comment: It works! I created a code that spits presigned url, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python script that spits presigned urls.

```
 import sys
 from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

 def sign(bucket, path, access_key, secret_key, https, expiry):
       c = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
       return c.generate_url(
              expires_in=long(expiry),
              method='GET',
              bucket = bucket,
              key=path,
              query_auth=True,
              force_http=(not https)
    )
```

The presigned urls can be accessed by any cloud service as long they are created by authorised user. Google happily accepts these urls. One can add expiry as well, thus avoiding making the entire bucket public.